# Как добавить номер телефона в базу с "+" Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как добавлять номера в базу с "+" например `+380991111111`, при добавлении плюс исчезает куда то.
пример

```
$query = DB::table('wallets')->insert(
                    ['wallet' => '+380991111111',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'month_limit' => 'monthLimit',
                    'status' => 'statu',
                    'type' => 'type',
                    'group' => 'group',
                    ]);
```

Comment: Структуру таблицы (или миграцию) для `wallets` покажите, пожалуйста. Может быть, у вас там стоит `INT`.

Comment: http://i.share.pho.to/a790ec46_o.png Вот , VARCHAR(15)

Comment: Почему у вас кодировка `big_chinise_ci`? Как проверяете, что плюс исчез?

Comment: Про кодировку не видел, это Mysql Workbench так сам сделал, я не менял кодировку, а проверяю как?! Ну в поле записывается значение без +. Поменял на utf8 ничего не поменялось